# Get content of HTML comment tag with Selenium

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, comments

I find it difficult to get the content of an HTML comment tag `<!-- stuff -->` included in the `head` tag of an HTML page using **python 2.7** and **selenium**.

```
<head>
   <!-- I would like to get this sentence -->
   [...]
</head>
```

I got the XPath of that comment using FirePath/FireBug (so I am assuming it is correct): `html/head/comment()[1]`.

Then:

- this `given_driver.find_element_by_xpath('html/head/comment()[1]')` gives me `InvalidSelectorException` saying `Message: The given selector html/head/comment()[1] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
  InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "html/head/comment()[1]" is: [object Comment]. It should be an element.`
- this `head_element = given_driver.find_element_by_xpath('html/head')` then gives me the whole HTML code in the `head` tag with `head_element.get_attribute('innerHTML')` like: `u'<!-- I would like to get this sentence -->\n         [...]`

But I would like to get just the content of the comment tag inside the `head` tag. I am wondering this is not possible with Selenium, but it seems strange to me. How could I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Selenium API doesn't support the comment node. However you could easely get the comment with this piece of JavaScript:

```py
head = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("head")
comment = get_element_comment(head)
print(comment)
```

```py
def get_element_comment(element):
    return element._parent.execute_script("""
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0].childNodes)
        .filter(function(e) { return e.nodeType === 8 })
        .map(function(e) { return e.nodeValue.trim() })
        .join('\n');
      """, element)
```

Comment: I've used BeautifulSoup to solve it this way: `head_content_soup = BeautifulSoup(given_driver.find_element_by_xpath('html/head').get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'html.parser')
  element_from_comment_tag = head_content_soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))` I just wished there could have been a way to do it using Selenium

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the page source and find (parse) the required comment from there. Something like this:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("your url");
var src = driver.PageSource;
```

Then parse `src`